# How can I split a string by white spaces that are not precedent by a certain character?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want to split a string only at white spaces that does not have a certain delimiter (: in my case) before it. E.g.:

```
$string = "Time: 10:40 Request: page.php Action: whatever this is Refer: Facebook";
```

Then from something like this I want to achieve an array such that:

```
$array = ["Time: 10:40", "Request: page.php", "Action: whatever this is", "Refer: Facebook"];
```

I've tried the following so far:

```
$split = preg_split('/(:){0}\s/', $visit);
```

But this is still splitting at every occurence of a white space.

Edit: I think I asked the wrong question, however "whatever this is" should stay as a single string

Edit 2: The bits before the colons are known and stay the same, maybe incorporating those somehow makes the task easier (of not splitting at whitespace characters in strings that should stay together)?

Comment: Its my bad for wording the question wrong, while your solution works great if there are no other white spaces, some of my string that should stay together have additional white spaces in, so things like "whatever this is" should stay as a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead in your split regex:

```
/\h+(?=[A-Z][a-z]*: )/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I6e9Lo/2)

Regex `\h+(?=[A-Z][a-z]*: )` matches 1+ whitespaces that is followed by a word starting with upper case letter and a colon and space.

Comment: `whatever this is` should stay as single string,

Comment: thank you! is it possible to modify this so that it accounts for some of the bits before the colon being a two digit uppercase string? stuff like "AT", "AB" does not split properly : "Action: This Example BB: Bla bla Request: 555". otherwise amazing answer, thank you!

Comment: @peterxz: Try: `/\h+(?=[A-Z]+[a-z]*: )/`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it

```
$string = "Time: 10:40 Request: page.php Action: whatever this is Refer: Facebook";

$split = preg_split('/\h+(?=[A-Z][a-z]*:)/', $string);

dd($split);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to match what is before the colon and then match upon the next part that starts with a space, non whitespace chars and colon:

```
\S+:\h+.*?(?=\h+\S+:)\K\h+
```

- `\S+:` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `\h+` Match 1+ times a horizontal whitespace char
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `(?=\h+\S+:)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, 1+ non whitespace chars and a colon
- `\K\h+` Forget what was matched using `\K` and match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qXzGDH/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/hbT1f)